# html selection forms not displaying correctly in phonegap

Tags: android, html, cordova

I'm trying to do the following:

```
 <select id="select_event" size="3">

            <option value="optAVal1">optAText1</option>

            <option value="optAVal2">optAText2</option>

            <option value="optAVal3">optAText3</option>

</select>
```

and I expect a selection form where I can see all the option values, but instead it acts as a drop down selection input. I'm doing this phonegap for an android app so I would think that html should apply normally as well. Is there some kind of restriction I dont know of?

Answer (score 0):

On personal experience mobile versions of browsers do not support the multi-line "select" element. Instead they render it as a drop down and show the options to the user when you touch/tap it. It might be for a concern in real state usage of the screen.

Edit:
I will suggest using the radio button options instead if you want to see all options in the screen.